# Orthonormal matrices and spectral norm

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Let $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ be a matrix with orthonormal columns ($d\le n$). By sub-multiplicativity, we have that
$\|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}\|_2 \le \|\mathbf{A}\|_2$ and  $\|\mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}\|_2 \le \|\mathbf{B}\|_2$ 
for arbitrary matrices $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times p}$.
In either case, does equality hold true in general?

I think in general $\|\mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}\|_2 = \|\mathbf{B}\|_2$ holds because $\|\mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}\|_2^2 = \|\mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}\|_2 = \|\mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{B}\| = \|\mathbf{B}\|_2^2$ but not the other case.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not true in general.
For example, let $d=1,m=1$, $n=2$ and $A = [0, 1]$, $X = [1,0]^T$.
Then we have
$$ \|AX\|_2 = 0 < \|A\|_2 = 1.$$